Where should I learn pytorch from?
I'm a undergraduate student. I've coded a three-node neural network (that works) based on my professor's guidance. However, I'd like to pursue a career in AI and Data Science, and I'd like to teach myself more about these properly in-depth. Are there any playlists or courses to learn using pytorch? That would be very helpful.

I don't know whether this is the right place for your question (maybe Cross Validated would be better), but to answer your question, there are many good books that you can get online, or for free, that have a lot of material about machine learning with Pytorch.
For example, there is "Deep Learning with Pytorch" by Stevens, Antiga, and Viehmann. There is also "Machine Learning with Pytorch and Scikit-Learn" by Raschka, Liu, and Mirjalili. Both of these give good material on machine learning using Pytorch, and I think they should be available for free online if you use your college account.
You could also try to build machine learning models by yourself as practice, using websites such as "MachineLearningMastery" etc, but you always have to check that their processes are "correct", as they may not always completely be.
